# Printing from chrome browser incorrectly applying mobile classes from media queries

Tags: css, google-chrome, printing, sass, media-queries

I am having trouble with mobile classes contained within media queries being incorrectly applied in a chrome browser on print.

When clicking <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> to print (through chrome browser) on desktop -> my mobile classes are being applied for the full screen, and the print version is incorrect. I want to ensure a user can print from desktop through chrome browser and mobile styles/classes/layouts will not get injected to the print version.

I have a print button on the page and a print specific stylesheet. There are no problems with the print button, the problem only occurs when browser printing and only in chrome. Weirdly, it works correctly in firefox and IE (go figure!).

I have tried including an additional print specific stylesheet in my header like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/_css_/print.css" type="text/css" media="print" />
```

And within this print.css stylesheet (compiled from SCSS) I've tried various different versions of wrapping all the styles in: `@media print { }` all to no avail.

Thank you in advance for help with this troublesome chrome printing!

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your mobile styles within `@media screen`:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
}
```